# CSS-Only Picture/Thumbnail Gallery

Tags: html, css

Although I've looked at many CSS-only scripts, I cannot figure out how to display the first image by default rather than have a blank space when this first opens. This must be CSS only - javascript and other "active content" not allowed. Please advise.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.gallerycontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  /*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}

.thumbnail img {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail:hover img {
  border: none;
}

.thumbnail span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
  left: -1000px;
  border: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
  /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallerycontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container:not(:hover) .thumbnail:first-child img + span {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 150px;
}
.container {
    width: 134px;
}
```

... should do it.

If `width:134px;` on `.container` is a problem, add a `margin-right` to it to compensate for the missing width.

To fix the hover issue on shorter images and the thumbs from jumping, you might want to add a few more lines, resulting in:

```css
.container:not(:hover) .thumbnail:first-child img + span {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 150px;
}
.container {
    width: 134px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.thumbnail:hover > img {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Updated snippet:

```css
.container {
  width: 134px;
  margin-right: 466px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container:not(:hover) .thumbnail:first-child img + span {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 150px;
}
.gallerycontainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  /*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}

.thumbnail img {
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail:hover > img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.thumbnail span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
  left: -1000px;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span {
  /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
  /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallerycontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x300" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x300" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/400x500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x350" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x350" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x250" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x250" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/350x500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/350x500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/450x500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/450x500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x200" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x200" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500x450" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500x450" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span>
    </a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb"><img border="0" src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="60" /><span><img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" width="500" /></span><br />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** this code needs to be loaded/applied at the end of your CSS. Or to modify the properties in your current CSS.

Answer (score 2):

### Rebuilt from scratch

**Compatibility:** Tested in Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge. Will work with all non-ancient browsers.

---

#### Here is the full snippet of what we are building below!

Some simple [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) smooth everything out.

```css
.gallery {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transition: width .1s;
}

.gallery>.thumb {
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery>.full {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 340px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 60vw;
  transition: opacity .3s, width .3s, left .1s;
}


/* Hide first image when other thumbnail is hovered*/

.gallery:hover>.full:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}


/*
1.No thumbnail is hovered:
  Show first image
2.Thumbnail is hovered
  Show image directly after hovered thumbnail
3.First thumbnail is hovered
  Show first image when first thumbnail is hovered
*/

.gallery>.full:nth-child(2),
.gallery>.thumb:hover+img,
.gallery>.thumb:first-child:hover+.full {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 925px) {
  .gallery>.full {
    left: 240px;
    transition: left .1s .05s
  }
  .gallery {
    width: 200px;
  }
}


/*Example styles */

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #001f3f;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />
</div>
```

---

#### The HTML

If you don't need to add anything to the image such as a text caption, then you can reduce the markup needed to the bare minimum; one container div with two images for each picture, one small and one large, like so:

```
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />
</div>
```

(If you need to add caption text to the full size image then you can keep wrapping the full sized images and change the CSS used here appropriately.)

#### The CSS

**Show the first full size image if nothing is selected:**

```
.gallery > .full:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Here is [some information on nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child).

**Hide the first image when other other thumbnails are hovered:**

```
.gallery:hover > .full:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

This actually hides the first full image when the gallery is hovered. This covers any of the thumbnails being hovered.

**Three selectors show the correct full size image when its thumbnail is hovered:**

```
.gallery > .full:nth-child(2),
.gallery > .thumb:hover + img,
.gallery > .thumb:first-child:hover + .full{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

1. Always show the first full size image
2. Show the full size image that is directly after the hovered thumbnail
3. Make sure that the first image is show when its thumbnail is hovered. This overrides that gallery hover hiding selector.

### The two columns of thumbnails

**Use CSS columns:**

```
.gallery  {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.gallery > .thumb {
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This displays two columns of images and spreads them evenly over 300px of width. The 100% width gets divided in two by the columns so they are the correct size. The padding is absorbed into the width thanks to `box-sizing: border-box`.

Here is [some information on CSS columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) and [box sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

**Display the full size images in the correct location:**

```
.gallery > .full {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 340px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 60vw;
}
```

The images are fixed to the top and pushed to the right of the thumbnails  with `left`. They will scroll. They are hidden by default with [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) and [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) means your cursor cannot interact with the images and they wont show when they themselves are hovered. The [viewport width unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) (`vw`) ensures the images will resize to suit the viewport.

**Reduce the size when the viewport gets smaller:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 925px){
  .gallery > .full {
    left: 240px; 
  }  
  .gallery {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

[Here is more information on @media.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media)

#### The full example again!

```css
.gallery {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transition: width .1s;
}

.gallery>.thumb {
  vertical-align: top;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 10px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.gallery>.full {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 340px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 60vw;
  transition: opacity .3s, width .3s, left .1s;
}


/* Hide first image when other thumbnail is hovered*/

.gallery:hover>.full:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}


/*
1.No thumbnail is hovered:
  Show first image
2.Thumbnail is hovered
  Show image directly after hovered thumbnail
3.First thumbnail is hovered
  Show first image when first thumbnail is hovered
*/

.gallery>.full:nth-child(2),
.gallery>.thumb:hover+img,
.gallery>.thumb:first-child:hover+.full {
  opacity: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 925px) {
  .gallery>.full {
    left: 240px;
    transition: left .1s .05s
  }
  .gallery {
    width: 200px;
  }
}


/*Example styles */

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #001f3f;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/900" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600" class="full" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" width="60" class="thumb" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700" class="full" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add following in first `span` under `a class=thumbnail` to show first image by default:

```
.container .thumbnail:first-child span{
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 49;
    left: 150;
}
```